# $\int \frac{1}{(x^2-4)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate:
$$\int \frac{1}{(x^2-4)^2}dx.$$
I tried Partial Fractions method first I write:
$$\frac{1}{(x^2-4)^2}=\frac{A}{X-2}+\frac{Bx+C}{(x-2)^2}+\frac{D}{x+2}+\frac{Ex+F}{(x+2)^2}.$$ 
We have:
$$A(x-2)(x+2)^2+(Bx+C)(x+2)^2+D(x+2)(x-2)^2+(Ex+F)(x-2)^2=1.$$

$$(A+B+D+E)x^3+(4A-2A+4B+C-4D+2D-4E+F)x^2+(4A-8+4B+4C+4D-8D+4E-4F)x+(-8A+4C+8D+4F)=1$$
So:
$$A+B+C+D+E=0$$
$$2A+4B+C-2D-4E+F=0$$
$$A+B+C-D+E=2$$
$$-8A+4C+8D+4F=1.$$

But how to find $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$?

I also tried substitution $$x=2\sec t$,$
but It caused some difficulty.

Comment: Solve the equation system!

Comment: How to solve the equation system? I cant do that

Comment: You have too many constants: start instead with
$$
\frac{1}{(x^2-4)^2}=\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x+2}+\frac{Cx + D}{x^2+2}.
$$
As a way to check in the future, keep in mind that the number of constants should match the degree of the denominator.

Comment: I Studied we have to use linear term when denominator is $(x-a)^2$ and why only constant  work?

Comment: The linear term goes on top when you have an unfactorable quadratic (such as $x^2 + 2$).  For $(x-a)^2$ you're meant to have only a constant.  Again, note that whichever rule you use, the number of constants should match the degree of the denominator.

Comment: As it turns out though, there is no repeated linear factor on the bottom in this case (once you factor correctly).  Keep in mind that $(x+2)^2 \neq x^2 + 2$

Comment: Can you explain where the $x^2+2$ comes from? The only way I see of factoring $(x^2-4)^2$ is $(x+2)^2(x-2)^2 = (x-2)(x+2)(x^2-4)$. If I were to add up $\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x+2}+\frac{Cx + D}{x^2+2}$, the denominator would be $(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+2)$ which is certainly not $(x^2-4)^2$.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Alexander51413

Comment: "For $(x−a)^2$ you're meant to have only a constant" good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the neatest approach is to square $\frac{1}{x^2-4}=\frac14\left(\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x+2}\right)$ to give$$\frac{1}{(x^2-4)^2}=\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{1}{(x-2)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}-\frac{2}{x^2-4}\right)=\frac{1}{32}\left(\frac{2}{(x-2)^2}+\frac{2}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{x-2}\right).$$Now you can integrate:$$\int\frac{dx}{(x^2-4)^2}=\frac{1}{32}\left(-\frac{2}{x-2}-\frac{2}{x+2}+\ln\left|\frac{x+2}{x-2}\right|\right)+C,$$where $C$ is locally constant and can change at each of $x=\pm2$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$x=2\text{sec}(\theta)$, $dx=2\text{sec}(\theta)\text{tan}(\theta)d\theta$ then:

$\int \frac{1}{(x^2-4)^2}dx=\int \frac{2\text{sec}(\theta)\text{tan}(\theta)}{(4\text{sec}^2(\theta)-4)^2}d\theta=\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{\text{sec}(\theta)\text{tan}(\theta)}{\text{tan}^4(\theta)}d\theta$
$$=\frac{1}{8}\int \text{ctg}^2(\theta)\text{csc}(\theta) d\theta= \frac{1}{8}(\int \text{csc}^3(\theta)d\theta-\int\text{csc}(\theta) d\theta)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Another way

Write numerator as $$\left(\dfrac{x+2-(x-2)}4\right)^2$$

Now $\dfrac1{(x+2)(x-2)}=\dfrac{x+2-(x-2)}{4(x+2)(x-2)}=?$

Comment: $\dfrac{(x+2-(x-2))^2}4=4$ did you mean writing numerator as $\dfrac{(x+2-(x-2)^2)}{4^2}$?

Comment: @hgs, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\frac{1}{(x^2-4)^2}=1/16\, \left( x-2 \right) ^{-2}-1/32\, \left( x-2 \right) ^{-1}+1/16\,
 \left( x+2 \right) ^{-2}+1/32\, \left( x+2 \right) ^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact approach with the substitution $x=2\cosh t$,

$$I= \int \frac{1}{(x^2-4)^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{8} \int \text{csch}^3 tdt
= -\frac{1}{8} \int \text{csch} t \>d(\coth t)$$
$$= -\frac{1}{8} \left(\text{csch} t \coth t + \int \text{csch} t \coth^2 tdt \right)$$
$$= -\frac{1}{8} \left(\text{csch} t \coth t + \int \text{csch} t dt\right)-I$$
$$=-\frac{1}{16}\left( \text{csch} t \coth t + \int \text{csch} t dt\right)$$
$$=-\frac{1}{16} \left( \text{csch} t \coth t+ \ln \tanh\frac t2 \right)+C$$